# how can i add an image in the signup form

Tags: flutter, dart

When i try to open the signup page and signup a new user i am getting this exception:error cannot open file. because of the picked image file but i have the file on my laptop and that is it's current path and when i try to leave it without initialization i am getting an error that it didn't get initialized even if  put late on it or the ? mark and i tried to put a link to the image from google and i got an exception:no such file or directory so what should i do
that is the authform file:

```
class Authform extends StatefulWidget {
  final void Function(String email, String password, String username,
      bool islogin, BuildContext ctx) submitfun;
  final bool isloading;

  Authform(this.submitfun, this.isloading);

  @override
  Authformstate createState() => Authformstate();
}

class Authformstate extends State<Authform> {
  final formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool islogin = true;
  String email = "";
  String password = "";
  String username = "";
  void pickimage(File pickedimage) {}

  void submit() {
    final isvalid = formkey.currentState!.validate();
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

    if (isvalid) {
      formkey.currentState!.save();
      widget.submitfun(
          email.trim(), password.trim(), username.trim(), islogin, context);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Form(
              key: formkey,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  if (!islogin) Userimagepicker(pickimage),
                  TextFormField(
                    key: ValueKey('email'),
                    validator: (val) {
                      if (val!.isEmpty || !val.contains('@')) {
                        return "please enter a valid email address";
                      }
                    },
                    onSaved: (val) => email = val!,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'email address'),
                  ),
                  if (!islogin)
                    TextFormField(
                      key: ValueKey('username'),
                      validator: (val) {
                        if (val!.isEmpty || val.length < 4) {
                          return "please enter a valid username";
                        }
                      },
                      onSaved: (val) => username = val!,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'username'),
                    ),
                  TextFormField(
                    key: ValueKey('password'),
                    validator: (val) {
                      if (val!.isEmpty || val.length < 7) {
                        return "please enter a valid password";
                      }
                    },
                    onSaved: (val) => password = val!,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'password'),
                    obscureText: true,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  if (widget.isloading) CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  if (!widget.isloading)
                    ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: submit,
                        child: Text(islogin ? 'login' : 'signup')),
                  if (!widget.isloading)
                    TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            islogin = !islogin;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Text(islogin
                            ? 'create new account'
                            : 'i already have an account'),
                        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                            textStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor)))
                ],
              ),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and that is the imagepicker file:

```
class Userimagepicker extends StatefulWidget {
 final void Function(File pickedimage) imagepickfun;

 Userimagepicker(this.imagepickfun);
 @override
 UserimagepickerState createState() => UserimagepickerState();
}

class UserimagepickerState extends State<Userimagepicker> {
 File pickedimage =
     File('C:\Users\georgederderian\Desktop\whatsapp image.jpg');

 final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();

 void pickimage(ImageSource src) async {
   final pickedimagefile = await picker.pickImage(source: src);
   if (pickedimagefile != null) {
     setState(() {
       pickedimage = File(pickedimagefile.path);
     });
     widget.imagepickfun(pickedimage);
   } else {
     print('no image selected');
   }
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       CircleAvatar(
         radius: 40,
         backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
         backgroundImage: FileImage(pickedimage),
       ),
       SizedBox(height: 10),
       Row(
         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
         children: [
           TextButton.icon(
             onPressed: () => pickimage(ImageSource.camera),
             icon: Icon(Icons.photo_camera_outlined),
             label: Text(
               'add image\n from camera',
               textAlign: TextAlign.center,
             ),
           ),
           TextButton.icon(
               onPressed: () => pickimage(ImageSource.gallery),
               icon: Icon(Icons.photo_album_outlined),
               label: Text(
                 'add image\n from gallery',
                 textAlign: TextAlign.center,
               ))
         ],
       )
     ],
   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is on your computer and not on the device running the app (emulator or phone).

and to use online images, you use image network instead of File

So you should be using **late File? pickedimage**
and use an **initial** icon or image asset/network before the image is picked